# operator norm of the product of a matrix and its near-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Edit**: I'm casting the problem in different perspective (originally suggested by the commenter below) that might be more helpful.  My original post can be found below the line.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive definite $n \times n$ matrices which are simultaneously diagonalizeable, i.e. $X = V A V^T $ and $Y = V B V^T$ for diagonal matrices $A = \text{diag}(a)$ and $B = \text{diag}(b)$.
Let $I \subset [n]$ denote a subset of the $n$ rows/columns of $X$ and $Y$.

I'd like to upper bound  the quantity $ \|(X_{I})^{-1} Y_I\|_2 $, where $X_I$ and $Y_I$ are the principal submatrices comprised of just the rows/columns with indices in $I$.

The naive approach is $ \|(X_{I})^{-1} Y_I\|_2 \le \|(X_I)^{-1}\|_2 \| Y_I\|_2 \le b_{\max} / a_{\min}$.
However, this naive approach does not account for the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are simultaneously diagonalizeable, and it is possible to get a substantially tighter bound in e.g. the special case $I = [n]$ (i.e. where we don't drop any rows/columns), in which case  we have $\|X^{-1}Y\|_2 = \| V \text{diag}(b/a) V^T\|_2 = \max_i (b_i / a_i)$.
Similarly, in the special case where $V$ is the identity, we also have $\|(X_I)^{-1}Y_I \| =\| \text{diag}(a/b)_I\|_2 = \max_i (b_i / a_i)$.
My question is whether the naive bound can be improved upon in the general case where $V$ is not the identity and $I \subset[n]$.

---

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ be a matrix with orthonormal columns, with $n > d$ (so $U$ is tall and thin). Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors with strictly positive entries.

I'm trying to upper-bound the operator norm of the matrix $M = (U^T \, \text{diag}(a) \, U)^{-1} (U^T \,\text{diag}(b)\, U)$.
In particular, I'd like to show that if $b \approx a$ (in some sense to be determined), then $\|M\|_2$ is small.

Now, if $d=n$, then the inverse could be computed in closed form as $(U^T \,\text{diag}(a) U)^{-1} = U^T \, \text{diag}(a)\, U$, so we would have $M=U^T \, \text{diag}(b/a) \, U$ and $\|M\|_2 = \max_i \{b_i / a_i\}$.
This is much sharper than the crude bound $\|M\|_2 \le \| (U^T \text{diag}(a) U)^{-1} \|_2 \; \| U^T \text{diag}(b) U \|_2= \max_i \{b_i\} \, / \, \min_i \{a_i\}$.  For example, consider $a=[1, 10, 100]$ and $b=[2, 11, 101]$.

Unfortunately, when $n > d$, this technique breaks.
Still, I would think that the naive bound $\|M\|_2 \le  \max_i \{b_i\} \, / \, \min_i \{a_i\}$ can be improved upon, even in this setting?

Comment: as a first cut -- you should be able to use Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing here

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So, if I imagine completing $U$ with the other $n-d$ columns to form $\tilde{U} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then by applying Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing to $\tilde{U}^T \text{diag}(a) \tilde{U}$ and $\tilde{U}^T \text{diag}(b) \tilde{U}$, then I should be able to get upper and lower bounds for each eigenvalue of $(U^T \text{diag}(a) U)^{-1}$ and $U^T \text{diag}(b) U$.  However, in order to bound $\|M\|_2$, don't I also need to know that the eigen_vectors_ of $(U^T \text{diag}(a) U)^{-1}$ and $U^T \text{diag}(b) U$ are aligned?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @user8675309, but I don't think that interlacing improves upon my naive bound.  We need an _upper_ bound on the _largest_ eigenvalue of $Y$ and a _lower_ bound on the _smallest_ eigenvalue of $X$.  However, interlacing gives us an interesting _lower bound_ on $\lambda_{\max}(Y)$ and an interesting _upper bound_ on $\lambda_{\min}(X)$, which is the wrong direction.  Specifically, interlacing tells us that $a_{(n-d)} \le \lambda_{\max}(Y) \le a_{(1)}$  and $b_{(n)} \le \lambda_{\min}(X) \le b_{(d+1)}$, where I'm using $a_{(i)}$ to denote the $i$-th largest entry of $a$.

Comment: You are right. Your problem *looks* so much like an interlacing problem that I skipped writing out the explicit bounds here based on pattern recognition.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway!